# Sequelize query with NOT IN clause and nested SELECT

Tags: orm, sequelize.js

I have an SQL query which I would like to express using the sequelize query syntax.

**DB Scheme**

- Users: (**id**, username, ...)
- Groups: (**id**, name, ...)
- User_Groups: (**id**, #groupId, #userId)

**Query Description**

Retrieve all users that are not yet part of a particular group.

**Raw SQL Query** (working)

```
SELECT User.id, User.email FROM Users as User 
  WHERE User.id NOT IN (
    SELECT User_Group.userId FROM User_Groups as User_Group 
    WHERE User_Group.groupId = ${groupId}
  )
```

**Where I'm blocked**

I tried to simulate a join using the sequelize `include` statement, but my brain is stuck transforming the nested SELECT query as well as the `NOT IN` operator...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It's not possible to represent sub-queries](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/sub-queries.html) other than using **Sequelize.literal** in the `where` clause like this:

```
const users = await database.User.findAll({
  where: Sequelize.where(Sequelize.literal(`(User.id NOT IN (
    SELECT User_Group.userId FROM User_Groups as User_Group 
    WHERE User_Group.groupId = '${groupId}'
  ))`)
}
```

or you can mix up **Op.notIn** with **Sequelize.literal**

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out the `Sequelize.literal` option. It pointed me into the right direction and finally to the limitation of sub-queries in sequelize...