# Sequelize generate complex query (SELECT WHERE IN)

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I need to get a complex query like this. To check user access to table1 data. Using ORM Sequelize js.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE id = 23
  AND "table2_id" IN
      (SELECT id
       FROM "table2"
       WHERE "table3_id" IN
             (SELECT id
              FROM "table3"
              WHERE "table_4" IN
                    (SELECT id
                     FROM table4
                     WHERE "table5_id" IN
                           (SELECT "id"
                            FROM "table5"
                            WHERE "userId" = 1))))
```

I tried to use include param

```js
const table1_item = await Table1.findOne({
        where: {id: id, '$table2.table3.table4.table5.user.id$': user.id},
        include: [
            {
                model: Table2,
                attributes: [],
                include: [{
                    model: Table3,
                    attributes: [],
                    include: [{
                        model: Table4,
                        attributes: [],
                        include: [{
                            model: Table5,
                            attributes: [],
                            include: [{
                                model: User,
                                attributes: [],
                            }]
                        }]
                    }]
                }]
            }
        ]
    });
```

But it generate query with JOIN's. And the DB is slowly returning many rows of data.

Answer (score 0):

The only option here is `Sequelize.literal` in `where`. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63752520/1376618) about similar question

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you can't use the [sequelize.query method](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js%7ESequelize.html#instance-method-query)? Sequelize has it specifically for complex queries like this:

```
const table1_item = await sequelize.query('SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE id = 23
  AND "table2_id" IN
      (SELECT id
       FROM "table2"
       WHERE "table3_id" IN
             (SELECT id
              FROM "table3"
              WHERE "table_4" IN
                    (SELECT id
                     FROM table4
                     WHERE "table5_id" IN
                           (SELECT "id"
                            FROM "table5"
                            WHERE "userId" = 1))));', 
    { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT });
```